# Why javascript console.log(1 + + " " + 3); sentence returns 4 and not "1 3"?

Tags: javascript, console.log, coercion

When the statement `console.log(1 +  + " " + 3);` is executed in the Chrome console, the result is `4` and not `"1 3"` as i would expect.

Can someone please explain why this is the case?

Comment: Never trust your intuition when using the Javascript `+` operator.

Comment: Explain why you expected `"1 3"`. Without knowing _why_ you thought that, and given that (as you've discovered) you thought wrong, we can't help to correct your misconceptions.

Comment: I know that + " " is been coerced to 0 because i can test it in the chrome console, but i want to know the reason behind this. I would expect to be coerced to an empty string.

In the book Javascript for web developers 3d edition says:

If, however, one of the operands is a string, then the following rules apply:
- If both operands are strings, the second string is concatenated to the fi rst.
 - If only one operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string and the result is
the concatenation of the two strings.

So where is the rule of + " " is 0 or where can i find it.

Comment: @Eddiev As explained in the answers, `+` is a unary operator (like `-`) that converts to a number. Upon coercing first all whitespace characters are trimmed and then the numeric value is returned. If the string contains a valid number, that number is returned, otherwise `0` in the case of `+""`, `+false`, `+null`, etc. and otherwise `NaN`. It’s basically identical to `Number()`. Coercing is not the same as concatenating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is called **coercion**.

In this case the **[unary plus operator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)** converts to number the expression at the right. If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to [NaN](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

```
+ " " //--> is coerced to 0
```

You can see some coercion examples in this Gist:
**[JavaScript Coercion](https://gist.github.com/jherax/9ac4d1602d30882f8cb0)**

Answer (score 2):

If you simply broke down the problem into its constituent parts and typed `+" "` into the console, you'd see that it evaluates to `0`. And `1+3+0` is `4`.

Answer (score 1):

The following operations are done when the statement is evaluated:

```
1 // one
+ // add
+ " " // implicitly convert " " to a number (0)
+ // add
3 // three
```

So basically `1 + 0 + 3`. There’s no string that enters this calculation. It’s converted to a number beforehand.

The `+` operator in this case is the *unary* `+` (see “coercion”).